# Why does web essentials add outdated css vendor prefix?

Tags: web-essentials

When I write a property in a .css file, web essentials ask me to automatically add vendor specific prefixes where needed; but it add prefixes for very old browsers :

[image: Prefix for Firefox 1]

Here, the prefix is for Firefox 1, 
though I asked the autoprefixer to target the "last 2 versions" :

[image: last 2 versions]

But when I write the same code in .less file, the compiled css contains the prefixes asked (in this case, none is added; but if I specify > 0%, all prefixes are). Is the plugin able to automatically add the prefixes only with less (or sass, I guess) ?